# determining recognizable or decidable (TM that accepts a TM)

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I'm having an issue determining whether certain languages are decidable,
 recognizable or neither.
The specific languages I'm referring to are of the following form
L = {<M> | for every w, M accepts w after at most |w|/2 steps}
L = {<M> | for every w, M accetps w after at most X steps}
L = {<M> | for every w, M accepts w after at least X steps}
L = {<M> | there is no input which M terminates in fewer than X steps}
L = {<M> | M is a Turing machine and the number of states of M is prime}

Up till now all the languages I encountered were usually taking an input of the form <M,w> which made it easy cause it was always some sort of a manipulation that required running the Turing machine M on the input w in some form, but I have no idea how to even start thinking regarding these languages, any direction or hint as to how to approach these sort of questions will be very helpful !

Comment: Does recognisable mean the same as computably enumerable?

Comment: Recognizable = recursive enumerable

Comment: One more thing that confuses me when it says for "every $w$" does that really mean for "every $w$" or just for "every $w$ that $M$ accepts"?

Comment: And if it's the second does it have to reject by $X$ steps too? or can it just not halt for example?

Comment: Regarding the first, its for every w and not every w that M accepts. And when it comes to rejection and halting you have no information regarding it , I can only assume that there is no rejection/non-halting as it does accept EVERY w there is. (I really am hoping I'm understanding this correctly >_<)

Comment: If you are reading it the right way we can say a couple of things about the languages at least that are not hard. Notice that 1 and 2 have recognisable complements since you can just dovetail over $w$'s until you find one that does not get accepted in time. For the same reason 3 has a recognisable complement since we dovetail again until we find a $w$ which gets accepted early. Same again for 4 since we dovetail till we find an input which terminates early.

Comment: 5 should be decidable since that's just a question about the coding of $<M>$ as a turing machine. You decode and count the number of states then figure out if that number is prime. All of those are decidable if tedious.

Comment: Obviously I've left the hard bits open, but maybe I at least gave you a couple of hints. I would guess that none of the languages except the last one are decidable (though I might be wrong). The usual way to prove that, that I recall is perform some reduction to the halting problem. (i.e. show that if you can decide these languages you can decide the halting problem with them as an oracle.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take everything you said in consideration and will try to give it another go !

Answer (score 3):

Something is funny (interesting) about the first language. To be in the first language, the machine must accept every string $w$ in at most $|w|/2$ steps. One might at first suspect that language would be undecidable, but it turns out to be decidable for a somewhat trivial reason.

What if $w$ has length $1$? Then $|w|/2$ is $1/2$. Steps are measured with natural numbers, and the machine cannot do anything in $0$ steps, so let's be generous and say the machine must accept $w$ after one step. The only way this can be done is by re-writing the symbol under the head to "1" (that is, "accept") and transitioning to the halting state. Those actions together take one step.

For the machine to be in the first language, this has to happen for every $w$ of length $1$. In other words, for every symbol of the input alphabet, the machine must immediately write a $1$ on the tape and transition to the halting state.  Indeed, the machine accepts every string of length $1$ in $1$ step if and only if the machine follows the previous sentence for every input of length $1$. And in that case, it accepts *every* string in $1$ step.

So we *can* decide whether a machine is in the first language: we only have to look at the state table for the machine and see whether it has all the transitions mentioned in the previous paragraph. That can be done by literally examining the code $\langle M \rangle$ for the machine.

A similar analysis will apply to the second language, as well: when the length of the input is much larger than $X$, the machine is unable to actually see then entire input in $X$ steps. So the machine accepts every string in $X$ or fewer steps if and only if it accepts every string of length $X+1$ in $X$ or fewer steps, because the behavior of the first $X$ steps is completely determined by the first $X$ symbols of the input. That is a finite number of strings that we need to test, so we can effectively determine whether a machine is in the second language.

Another similar analysis will apply to the fourth language. A machine halts on an input in fewer than $X$ steps if and only if the machine halts on the first $X+1$ symbols of the input in fewer than $X$ steps (because, when the machine halted in fewer than $X$ steps on the whole input, it never saw the $(X+1)$st symbol of the input). So a machine is in the fourth language if and only if there is no input of length $X+1$ for which the machine halts in fewer than $X$ steps. That is a decidable question; we only have to run the machine for $X$ steps on all inputs of length $X+1$ to answer it. So the fourth language is also decidable.

Comment: By the way, this shows one of the important differences between the Turing machine model of computation and the functional models in which the inputs are directly natural numbers. In the functional models, a machine can directly read the input "all at once", but in the Turing machine model it takes time just to read the whole input. This is why Turing machines are used to define computational complexity, because the time that they take to read the input is important in that context.

Comment: I now understand every one of those questions to its detail, thank you, just 1 thing regarding the first language I answered it a bit differently and correct me if I'm wrong, assuming the empty string is a possibility and its length is 0 hence |w|/2 = 0/2 = 0 , which means that every machine M that will be accepted must accept after 0 steps I.E. the starting state is also an accepting state which makes it possible to build a TM that checks if the Qstart is also Qaccept and if so the machine accepts M else it rejects it.

Comment: @Carl Can I assume that the third language is undecidable since you did not mention it in your answer?

Comment: Yes, the third language ("... at least ...") is undecidable.